# Trying to understand uboot image copying

Tags: u-boot

The following is snippet from `u-boot-xarm/include/configs/zynq_zc702.h`

```
"qspiboot=echo Copying Linux from QSPI flash to RAM...; \
                cp 0xFC100000 0x8000 ${kernel_size}; \
                cp 0xFC600000 0x1000000 0x8000; \
                echo Copying ramdisk...; \
                cp 0xFC800000 0x800000 ${ramdisk_size};\
                ping 10.10.70.101;\
                go 0x8000\0" \
```

Can somebody explain what is happening in these two lines:

```
                    cp 0xFC100000 0x8000 ${kernel_size}; \
                    cp 0xFC600000 0x1000000 0x8000; \
```

How these addresses are chosen? And why so many addresses?

Answer (score 1):

It is copying a kernel and initrd stored in flash out to RAM before starting linux. Command cp is documented in [cp - memory copy](http://www.denx.de/wiki/view/DULG/UBootCmdGroupMemory#Section_5.9.2.4.)

Source addresses are areas in flash that don't hold the flash u-boot code. Destination addresses are areas in RAM that u-boot is not using for its own code/data in execution.

Comment: In the two lines,I dont see initrd anywhere. In the first line I can see that kernelis being copied from 0xFC100000 to 0x8000.   But in  the second line: source add=0xFC600000,destination=0x1000000, then what is 0x8000?   and what is being copied ? Can you elaborate ?

Comment: I suggest you look into the technical meaning of terms such initrd and ramdisk. You may find they are related.

Comment: I am not having issues in intrd/intirmafs. I just want to know what are those three nubers in second line?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't come across a definition for the syntax of the QSPI flash to RAM copy command but the pattern seems to be

```
cp src_addr dst_addr copy_size
```

The second copy is for the devicetree (`devicetree.dtb`) which just by coincidence has a size (0x8000) that is the same as the beginning address for the Linux kernel (0x8000) in RAM.